# Calculate the trajectory integral given by the equations $x^2+y^2=z^2,y^2=ax$ from the point $(0,0,0)$ to $(a,a,\sqrt{2}a)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

> Calculate the trajectory  integral $$I=\int_{\gamma}zdl$$ where $\gamma$ is a curve obtained by the intersection  of the surfaces given by the equations $x^2+y^2=z^2,y^2=ax$ from the point $(0,0,0)$ to $(a,a,\sqrt{2}a)$

** My attempt **

We need to parametrize the expression, note that the parametrization of $\gamma$ is given by $x=t$,$y=\sqrt{at}$,$z=\sqrt{t^2+at}$ where $t\in [0,a]$.

Now we find the derivatives of our parametrization $x^{\prime}=1$,$y^{\prime}=\frac{a}{2\sqrt{at}}$,$z^{\prime}=\frac{2t+a}{2 \sqrt{t^2+at}}$

now note that our parametrization is $C:[0,a]\rightarrow(t,\sqrt{at},\sqrt{t^2+at})$ where $C$ is injective trajectory, now we find
$||C^{\prime}(t)||=\sqrt{(x^{\prime})^2+(y^{\prime})^2+(z^{\prime})^2}$ and
$||C^{\prime}(t)||=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{8t^2+9at+2a^2}{t^2+at}}$ now we substitute it in $I$ like a
$$I=\int_{\gamma}zdl=\frac{1}{2}*\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{t^2+at}\sqrt{\frac{8t^2+9at+2a^2}{t^2+at}}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{a} \sqrt{8t^2+9at+2a^2}dt$$
Finally solving the latest integral we get
$$I=\int_{\gamma}zdl=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{256}a\left(-72 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{a^2}+200 \sqrt{19} \sqrt{a^2}+17 \sqrt{2} a \log \left(8 \sqrt{a^2}+9 a\right)-17 \sqrt{2} a \log \left(4 \sqrt{38} \sqrt{a^2}+25 a\right)\right)$$
And like the intersection is two lines we multiply it by $2$ and we get
$$I=\int_{\gamma}zdl=(\frac{1}{256}a\left(-72 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{a^2}+200 \sqrt{19} \sqrt{a^2}+17 \sqrt{2} a \log \left(8 \sqrt{a^2}+9 a\right)-17 \sqrt{2} a \log \left(4 \sqrt{38} \sqrt{a^2}+25 a\right)\right)$$
Is my approach fine?  or probably I forget some detail.

I think that it wrong because usually when I apply a parametrization the integrand is much easy than it, and i had to compute the Integral in Wolphram Mathematica , because it is so much large.
Please any help, hit or comment are useful and appreciate .
Thanks so much for read me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whichever way you look at it, it is not going to be a straightforward integral.

Please note the intersection curve is given by as below and we have to integrate over this curve from point $(0,0,0)$ to $(a,a,\sqrt2 \,a)$.

$x^2 + ax - z^2 = 0 \implies (x+\frac{a}{2})^2 - z^2 = \frac{a^2}{4}$

This is equation of a hyperbola and I would consider hyperbolic parametrization instead.

$x = -\frac{a}{2} + \frac{a}{2} \cosh t = \frac{a}{2} (\cosh t - 1) = a \sinh^2 \frac{t}{2}$

$z = \frac{a}{2} \, \sinh t$

$y = a \, \sinh \frac{t}{2}$

where $0 \leq t \leq \sinh^{-1}(2 \sqrt2)$ (bound based on $0 \leq z \leq \sqrt 2 \, a$).

So $r(t) = (a \sinh^2 \frac{t}{2}, a \sinh \frac{t}{2}, \frac{a}{2} \, \sinh t)$

$r'(t) = (a \sinh \frac{t}{2} .\cosh \frac{t}{2}, \frac{a}{2} \, \cosh \frac{t}{2}, \frac{a}{2} \, \cosh t)$

$||r'(t)|| = \displaystyle \frac{a \sqrt {2 \cosh 2t + \cosh t + 1}}{2 \sqrt2}$

$I = \displaystyle \frac{a^2}{4 \sqrt2} \int_0^{\sinh^{-1}(2 \sqrt2)} (\sinh t \sqrt {2 \cosh 2t + \cosh t + 1}) \, dt = \frac{a^2}{4 \sqrt2} \times 8.22216 \approx 1.4535a^2$

Comment: Great work, now I´m analyzing your answer and try to bound it with my answer and compare, for the momen im only can say "nice solution" very clear.

Comment: Thanks so much, I´m glad with your answer every is better see other ways to do the same thing.

Comment: @BrienNavarro you are welcome

Comment: A least question. Can you explain me how do you get the hyperbolic  parametrization of the curve? or given me a link where i can read about it, im searching in google,but i dont get read some about it topic, exept the basic definitions about hyperbolic functions using exponential function.

Comment: @BrienNavarro pls see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Parametric_equations. It is given for $x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1$. For us here, $a = b = a/2$. But for us the center of the hyperbola (where both asymptotes meet) is not at the origin but at (x = -a/2, z = 0). So you would see that adjustment in the parameterization.

Answer (score 0):

Glanced at your solution and did not find anything out or ordinary or red flags.

But the surfaces look like cylindrical coordinates might be used that should simplify the computation. Try to use those.

Comment: Thanks I'm try to do your suggestion,